# Java OData client using SAP Cloud SDK problems

Tags: odata, sap-cloud-sdk

I am having troubles with updating my OData Client.
I would refer to [How to call bound functions / actions inside Java client using SAP Cloud SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66279799/how-to-call-bound-functions-actions-inside-java-client-using-sap-cloud-sdk) where people from SAP helped me alot, thanks!

Issue is, I wanted to update dependency to last version of SAP Cloud SDK because of new functionality that supports bounded functions and actions.

Back then (4 months ago), I had written myself documentation how to generate and use OData Java client properly, using SAP Cloud SDK. Quite a number of people was succesful back then with installing.

Now, 4 months later, I cannot generate properly client. I have installed *lombok* and also set it as reference in Eclipse and am using latest Eclipse (2021-06).
I will put screenshots of my errors. It says like my properties are not generated properly and that 1 method is missing - getOdataType().

[image: Properties missing]

[image: Get OdataType not implemented]

These problems just started to occur last 2 weeks or so.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you outline in more detail how you exactly generate the OData client in your setup?

Comment: Of course! 
1. Eclipse IDE - new Maven Project
2. Create new folder called edmx and add metadata.xml file to that folder
3. Add all required dependencies (sap.cloud.sdk, org.projectlombok, javax.inject)
4. Update Maven project
5. Move all generated stuff from target to src/main/java

After last step, I get thousand of errors, like I said in original question, these steps worked just fine few months back

Comment: This still looks like a setup issue to me. I can't quite see it from your screenshot, but it looks like the necessary fields and `@Getter` annotations are generated correctly and your IDE seems to not recognise them.

What is the result if you run `mvn clean compile` in a command line? If that works we can be sure it is an IDE problem.

Comment: Maven works fine, it generates everything. 
Can you explain what you mean with Setup Issue? As I have already reinstalled Eclipse few times. Manually installed maven etc.. I am still getting same errors. It looks like it doesnt generate mapping correctly, because for example above, getName(), it says it is not implemented. I really dont know how to proceed, as everything worked completely fine few months ago

Comment: With "setup issue" I mean that it seems like Eclipse or one of its plugins isn't configured correctly. IF `mvn clean compile` works then that means there is no problem with the Java code itself, neither with the generated nor with your own code. I'd recommend looking for advice from experts on Eclipse, Lombok and the related plugins.